# compute tangent map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:O(n)\rightarrow O(n), f(M)=M^3$ be a map, $O(n)$ are the orthogonal matrices. Calculate the tangent map at $I$.

My idea would be to firstly calculate the tangent space at $I$, it is the kernel of the $g'(I)$ ($g(X)=XX^T -I$ determines the orthogonal matrices)and it consists of precisely antisymmetic matrices. Then we could proceed by taking a chart $\phi$ around $I$, and the answer would be $H\mapsto (\phi\circ f\circ\phi ^{-1})'(\phi (I))H$, but I am not seeing an easy way to find $\phi$. I think there is a possibility of extracting it from the submersion, but it seems lengthy. Some other approach?

Comment: maybe we can calculate the tangent map of $M\mapsto M^3$ on whole of $M(n)$, it should be just $M\mapsto 3M$ and then it is just the restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us compute the tangent space at the identity $I \in O(n)$.
Define a map $\Phi:M(n) \to M(n)$ by $\Phi(A) = A^TA$.

Clearly $O(n)$ is the level set $\Phi^{-1}(I)$, so the tangent space at $I$ is just $T_IO(n) = ker\{\Phi_*: T_I M(n) \to T_I M(n)\}$.

Let $B \in T_I M(n)$. The curve $\alpha(t) = I + tB$ passes through $I$ at $t=0$ and its derivative at $t=0$ is $B$. So we can compute
$$\Phi_*(B) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm {dt}}|_{t=0}(\Phi\circ \alpha) (t) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm {dt}}|_{t=0}((I+tB)^T(I+tB) = B + B^T $$

Therefore $T_IO(n) = ker\{\Phi_*: T_I M(n) \to T_I M(n)\} = \{B \in M(n) \mid B = - B^T\}$.

Now to calculate the tangent map of $f(M) = M^3$ at $I$ we can use the same method:

$$f_*(B) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm {dt}}|_{t=0}(f\circ \alpha) (t) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm {dt}}|_{t=0} (I+tB)^3 = 3B$$

Comment: Good, but when we calculate $f _*$ shouldn't we have a curve $\alpha$ that is completely contained in $O(n)$ ?

Comment: Well, technicaly you're right. However we can do the computation in $T_I M(n)$ and obtain the above result, then since the tangent map is independent of the particular curve chosen, it would hold as a special case for a curve contained in $O(n)$.